# .net compact framework accessing audio metadata

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

Are there any libraries which exist for accessing audio (mp3 wmw) metadata using the .net compact framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [OpenNETCF](http://www.opennetcf.com): http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/f3fc3169-4143-54bc-1594-186da1fb01c2.htm ?

Answer (score 0):

or maybe http://home.fuse.net/honnert/hundred/?UltraID3Lib

Answer (score 0):

[BeyondPod](http://www.codeplex.com/beyondpod) is an open source RSS reader that supports mp3 podcasts. Download the sources and you will find code for reading mp3 ID3 tags.